# Deferencing type maps

Tags: dictionary, go

I am trying to dereference a channel and use the payload in the channel to check if there is an entry in the map or not.

If the map is of not type it works but if the map has a type I always get the error that type `<map>` is not an expression.

```
type writechan chan UserProfile
type usersmap map[string]UserProfile
var  myuserprofile UserProfile
myuserprofile = <-myuserchannel
var username = myuserprofile.name

if _, ok := usersmap[username]; ok {
    fmt.Println("Already registered ")
} else {
    usersmap[username] = myuserprofile
}
```

The error message says type usersmap is not an expression" in the if line . If I don't use the type usermap but a normal map say map[string]string it works fine.

Comment: Please redo the whole tour once more: https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

Comment: usersmap is a type, not a value. Perhaps you meant `var usersmap map[string]UserProfile`?

Comment: "I am trying to dereference a channel" - no you're not. I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do, but "dereference a channel" isn't a thing that exists.

Answer (score 3):

```
type usersmap map[string]UserProfile
```

This is a [type declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations), it does not create a variable named `usersmap`. After this type declaration you may use the `usersmap` (type) identifier to create a variable like this:

```
var umap usersmap
```

And to initialize it:

```
umap = make(usersmap)
```

Or in one line:

```
var umap = make(usersmap)
```

Or using a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) with initialization:

```
umap := usersmap{}
```

Also to create a variable of map type you don't necessarily have to create a new type, you may simply write:

```
var umap = make(map[string]UserProfile)
```